# Execute ASP.NET Membership Login from codebehind in button click handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, code-behind, wizard

I'm trying to seamlessly log in the user without prompting for credentials as part of a `<asp:Wizard>` process. My strategy is to handle the NextButtonClick event and login the user in code. I already have the user's credentials saved in session variables.

Is it possible to login a user in code? Will a hidden `<asp:Login>` control behind the scenes be required?

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication/ Setting some kind of verified user flag etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [programmatic login with .net membership provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243851/programmatic-login-with-net-membership-provider)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're storing their credentials in session, I hope you are encrypting them.

But yes, if you have their credentials already, you can do:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
```

You can also run:

```
if(Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)) {
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
}
```

before hand to make sure that you have the correct username and password.

Comment: I'm pretty sure anything you put into Session can be hijacked and therefore storing things like credit card information or passwords is a bad idea.

Comment: For session security, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027023/does-sensitive-asp-net-session-data-need-to-be-encrypted

Answer (score 2):

```
// This will redirect the user (check Jack Marchetti's answer for other option)
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text, false);
```

This will issue the authentication ticket for the user

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FormsAuthentication then just issue a session cookie:

```
// pass true to create a persistent cookie
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("userNameHere", true);
```