# Storing a Custom Object in a web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, session, caching

I am at a new company and I am building a wizard for a web app, (.Net/4.0). The user goes to a few separate screens during the wizard process and must return to the original screen before completion of the wizard. This is different from how they normally do this. But this is how it is TO BE DONE.

One option is to store the result of each panel in the main screen in the DB. So then, when the user leaves & redirects back. I could check for a querystring then call a datareader and populate original values appropriately.

The option I chose:
I have created an object and I am storing the result of the user input into it. When users leave & redirect back, check via querystring and populate control values via the BO.

I am storing the object in `HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("BO")` and calling that.

My question is, is that a bad way of doing this? 
If it isn’t what things might I want to do to make sure that object is removed from the session no matter what when the user exits the wizard.
If it is bad what would you do? I am not afraid of constructive criticism, I am new at this.

Comment: I guess storing in session is a god idea, i would do it that way. Re-tagging the question though as i feel its primarily a ASP.net question

Comment: Ok, do I need to do anything first to best store. Some sort of serialzation? Is that handles on its own. What about removing it. I want it gone obviously when the wizard is complete. But what about other things, lost connectio, timeouts ect...

Comment: Sorry to have replied so late, but i see the answer you have selected pretty much sums up what i would have said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something like this using the `Session` object. As far as performance(serialization) and things like that I would have to say thats on a case by case basis, if your custom classes are large and contain multiple other custom classes then serialization could be helpful but if they are relatively small and contain only primitive data types then serialization would probably be over kill and would quickly become counter productive.

As far as controlling how long the object stays in the session, you've said that in order to complete the wizard they have to go back to the start page or controller page or whatever you want to call it. So I would think when they click "Save" or "Complete" you could include a line at the end of your save function like `Session("BO") = nothing` (or `Session.Remove("BO")` will accomplish the same thing) and that would release the object from the `Session` container. If you want to clear the session when they navigate away from the page before completing the wizard then that could get a little more troublesome. As for lost connections and time outs and things like that, my understanding is that the browser treats both of those scenarios as if the session was abandoned so the next time the user opens your page it would be a completely new session.

But instead of worrying about that what I have done in the past is to make sure that every time the wizard starts it clears out the `Session` member that I planned on using, if it is not already `nothing` and then re-create it with a fresh object.

The only issue with either the `Session` approach or the `viewstate` approach is that neither are particularly secure so if you are dealing with sensitive data you may want to encrypt the value stored in the `Session`.

This article helped me when i was first starting to work with Cacheing and Session objects.
[Cache Management in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12097/Cache-Management-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: Do you know any good articles on encrypting the data stored in the Session ?

Comment: While googling around I came across this other stack overflow question, if you can dig through the petty arguing then there is some good information in there. Basically the jist is, you don't really need to encrypt session data as long as you are confident in your server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027023/does-sensitive-asp-net-session-data-need-to-be-encrypted

Answer (score 1):

If the wizard is all on the same page, just posting back to get to each screen of the wizard, you can use viewstate to achieve this. This gets around what you brought up, potentially having the object remain in session, even when the user leaves the wizard.

See the following article on msdn about viewstate:
[ASP.NET View State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx)

> You can also use view state to store application data that is specific
>   to a page.

There are some caveats to using viewstate though. You don't want to pipe down extremely large amounts of data to the users browser for state management. Classes stored in viewstate must also be serializable. Quoting the msdn article:

> View state information is serialized into XML and then encoded by
>   using base-64 encoding, which can generate large amounts of data. When
>   the page is posted to the server, the contents of view state are sent
>   as part of the page postback information. If view state contains a
>   large amount of information, it can affect performance of the page.
>   Test the performance of your pages by using typical data for your
>   application to determine whether the size of view state is causing
>   performance problems.

and

> ...the class must be compiled with the Serializable attribute so that its
>   values can be serialized for view state.

For alternatives to using viewstate, see the following on msdn:
[ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)

Comment: The problem is they use a modal overlay that isn't the same page it redirects to a whole new .aspx page and I had to write code to redirect back if the page is accessed coming from this wizard. The querystring. I have dont this with WCF, and I have code at home that does this via Current. Request. But we request another page so current.request doesnt have the lifetime I need to accomplish this.